# Normal Approximation to find probability of stopping at a red light at least 15 times

Tags: probability, statistics

Samantha and Julian are driving to a party out of town. They must pass through $40$
stoplights before they reach their destination. Each hour there is $35$ minutes of green
light, $10$ minutes of yellow light and $15$ minutes of red light at each stoplight. Assume all
lights change randomly. During Samantha and Julian’s drive, what is the probability that
they will have to stop more than $15$ times? (Samantha is driving and never brakes for
yellow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome here.

As all lights change randomly, this gives us $\frac 14$ probability of red light (lets call it *success*)and $\frac 34$ otherwise (lets call it *failure*). Now you want to calculate the probaility of $15$ successes in $40$ trials . This is what binomial distribution is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

For more than $15$ success. You'll have to add up the probabilities of 16 success,... to 40 success or calculate the complementary probability. One way is to really add these up.

Alternative way is to use the normal approximation to binomial , i.e, $\text {Binomial} (n,p) \equiv \text {Normal} (np,np(1-p)$. Then the sum becomes an integral.

Hope this helps. 
Also you can consider continuity correction. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction

Comment: Yes, but I'm not looking for 15 successes. I'm looking for at least 16 successes (more than 15 times).

Comment: ok, i'll edit my answer.